# How to insert column from a file to another file at multiple places

Tags: pandas, bash

I would like to insert columns no. 1 and 2 from file no. 2 into file no. 1 after every second column and till the last column.

File1.txt (tab-separated, column range from 1-2400 and cell range from 1-4500)

```
 ID   IMPACT  ID   IMPACT   ID  IMPACT
 51   0.288  128   0.4557  156  0.85
625   0.858   15   -0.589   51  0.96
  8   0.845    7   0.5891
```

File2.txt (consist of only two-tab separated column with 19000 raws)

```
   ID IMPACT 
   18     -1
  165     -1
   41     -1
   11     -1
```

Output file

```
 ID  IMPACT  ID  IMPACT  ID  IMPACT  ID  IMPACT  ID  IMPACT  ID  IMPACT
 51  0.288   18      -1 128  0.4557  18      -1 156    0.85  18      -1
625  0.858  165      -1  15  -0.589 165      -1  51    0.96 165      -1
  8  0.845   41      -1   7  0.5891  41      -1              41      -1 
             11      -1              11      -1              11      -1
```

I tried the below commands but it's not working

```
paste <(cut -f 1,2 File1.txt) <(cut -f 1,2 File2.txt) <(cut -f 3,4 File1.txt) <(cut -f 1,2 File2.txt)......... > File3
```

Prob: It starts sifting the File2.txt column value into different columns after the highest cell of File1.txt

```
paste File1.txt File2.txt > File3.txt
awk '{print $1 "\t" $2 "\t" $3 "\t" $4 "\t" $5 "\t" $6 "\t" $3 "\t" $4....}' File3.txt > File4.txt
```

This do the job, however it mixup the value of File1.txt from one column to another column.
I tried everything but failed to succeed.
Any help would be appreciated, however, bash or pandas would be better. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the two leading spaces in file File2.txt part of the file?

Comment: @Cyrus No they are not leading space, I added it, to look properly formated on screen, The file is in tab-separated format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="\t"                     # tab-separated data
}
NR==FNR {                           # hash fields of file2
    a[FNR]=$1                       # index with record numbers FNR
    b[FNR]=$2
    next
}
{                                   # print file1 records with file2 fields
    print $1,$2,a[FNR],b[FNR],$3,$4,a[FNR],b[FNR],$5,$6,a[FNR],b[FNR]
}
END {                               # in the end
    for(i=(FNR+1);(i in a);i++)     # deal with extra records of file2
        print "","",a[i],b[i],"","",a[i],b[i],"","",a[i],b[i]
}' file2 file1
```

Output:

```
ID      IMPACT  ID      IMPACT  ID      IMPACT  ID      IMPACT  ID      IMPACT  ID      IMPACT
51      0.288   18      -1      128     0.4557  18      -1      156     0.85    18      -1
625     0.858   165     -1      15      -0.589  165     -1      51      0.96    165     -1
8       0.845   41      -1      7       0.5891  41      -1                      41      -1
                11      -1                      11      -1                      11      -1
```

Comment: It is working perfectly. I took some time to check if it work perfectly on real data and yeah it's beautiful. Thank you sir for your help

Comment: Yup, Just came to know that I need to accept it. Thank you. Have a good day sir